# How do I apply padding to a list of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, padding, mfcc

I have this function padding function.

It takes `X` (a list of numpy arrays of dimensions `(13,n)` where `n` varies between 0-99 with each array) and returns and returns `X_new` which should also be a list of numpy arrays that are all shape `(13,99)` after padding.

```
X_new = []
for x in X:
    shp_1 = len(x[1])
    if shp_1 != targetdim:
        X_new.append(np.pad(x[1], (0, targetdim - shp_1), 'constant', constant_values=0))
    else:
        X_new.append(x)
```

Checking its output by checking the shape of the arrays in `X_new`

```
(13, 99)   #correct dimensions 
(13, 99)
(99,)      #wrong 
(13, 99)
(13, 99)
(13, 99)
(13, 99)
(99,)
(13, 99)
(99,)
(13, 99)
```

`X_new.append(np.pad(x[1], (0, targetdim - shp_1), 'constant', constant_values=0))` works as intended as it pads column x[1] to 99 if needed.

The problem is that the function only appends the padded array in `x[1]` to `new_list, x[0]` is discarded.
The result is that where padding is applied the output shape is `(99,)` instead of the desired `(13,99)`.

My question is how do I resolve this issue with append?

In short, my the goal is to reproduce list X with a list of padded arrays, any alternative methods of achieving this goal are also welcome.

Comment: If `X` is a list of arrays, and what to pad each, you should do `np.pad(x,...)`.  Why the `x[1]`?  If `x` is (13,n) you can get `n` by `x.shape[1]`.  I wonder if the `(99,)` shape comes from `x` with are not 2d?  You might want to verify the shape of all `x`.

Comment: @hpaulj To address each of your suggestions. `np.pad(x,...` doesn't seen to work, column x[1] is unchanged.  The (99,) shape occurs because append can only take one argument, we tell the function to append the padded x[1] to new_list but we ignore x[0] . I need someway of appending both x[0] and padded x[1] to the same row in new_list. Something like this   `X_new.append(x[0], np.pad(x, (0, targetdim - shp_1), 'constant', constant_values=0))`. I checked the shapes of all x's and they are all (13,n).

Comment: The initial description talks of `X` as a list of array, each with a dimension `(13,n)`.  I don't understand what `x[0]` and `x[1]` are referencing (other than the initial rows of the 13 rows).   Without a small concrete example, I can't help you.